# Grails does not fill in foreign-key field for one-to-many relation

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm new to grails and must be missing something important in trying to define a one-to-many mapping without using a join-table.

I have a domain object **Foo**

```
class Foo {

  static hasMany = [remarks: ChangeRemark]

  static mapping = {
      remarks column:'PART_REMARKS_ID', joinTable:false
  }
}
```

and another domain object **ChangeRemark**

```
class ChangeRemark {

  String remark
  String name

}
```

I initialize a Foo object, and add two ChangeRemark objects to it as such

```
    ChangeRemark remark = new ChangeRemark(remark:"test", name:"t").save(flush:true)
    ChangeRemark remark2 = new ChangeRemark(remark:"test2", name:"y").save(flush:true)

    Foo foo = new Foo().save(flush:true)

    foo.addToRemarks(remark).save(flush:true)
    foo.addToRemarks(remark2).save(flush:true)
```

When I print out the size of the remarks on foo it is indeed 2, however the database column for the foreign key *PART_REMARKS_ID* on the ChangeRemarks table is empty.  This means after I restart my application the connection between the object and the remarks can't be made

What am I missing to have grails insert the Foo id in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the join table use `belongsTo` to create a reference from `ChangeRemark` to `Foo`.

```
class Foo {

  static hasMany = [remarks: ChangeRemark]

}

class ChangeRemark {

  String remark
  String name

  static belongsTo = [foo: Foo]
}
```

When you do this, the `change_remark` table gets a `foo_id` foreign key. This means a `ChangeRemark` instance can reference only a *single* `Foo` instance; which I'm assuming is your intention.

This changes how you add `ChangeRemark`s:

```
ChangeRemark remark = new ChangeRemark(remark:"test", name:"t")
ChangeRemark remark2 = new ChangeRemark(remark:"test2", name:"y")

Foo foo = new Foo()

foo.addToRemarks(remark)
foo.addToRemarks(remark2)

foo.save(flush: true)
```

Basically, `Foo` is responsible for persisting itself and the `ChangeRemark`s.